# DF of Uniformly Joint Distributed RV's.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

I am trying to solve this math question, but I find myself getting stuck. I have a joint PDF of the form:

$f(x, y) = (\pi R^2)^{-1}$ for all $(x, y)$ in the circle with radius $R$, $0$ otherwise.

Now I have found the marginal PDF's in this question, but the question asks for me to find the marginal *DF* of each random variable $X$ and $Y$.

I think the Joint *DF* is $xyf(x, y)$, as taking the derivative with respect to $x$, then $y$ will give back the joint *PDF*, but I am unsure. If someone could help me out it would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: **To clarify:** by DF do you mean the Cummulative Distribution Function; more typically abbreviated as CDF?

Comment: The function you mention takes negative values, so it cannot be a distribution function.

Comment: OP, please write `$f(x, y) = (\pi R^2)^{-1}$` **not** `$f$($x$, $y$) = ($pi$*$R$^$2$)^(-$1$)$`. If you want to italicize something (regular text), use `*` or `_`, like `_this_` _this_, **not** `$this$` $this$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp, yes I am talking about the CDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a uniform distribution within the disc of radius $R$.

The support is thus $\big\{(x,y)\mid x\in(-R;R), y\in(-\sqrt{R^2-x^2~};\sqrt{R^2-x^2~})\big\}$

Therefore the marginal pdf for $X$ is:

$$f_X(s) ~=~ \int\limits_{-\sqrt{R^2-s^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-s^2}} (\pi R^2)^{-1}~\mathbf 1_{s\in (-R;R)}\operatorname d t $$

The marginal CDF for $X$ is then $$F_X(x) = \left(\int\limits_{-R}^x \int\limits_{-\sqrt{R^2-s^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-s^2}} (\pi R^2)^{-1}\operatorname d t \operatorname d s\right) \mathbf 1_{x\in(-R;R)}+\mathbf 1_{x\in[R;\infty)}$$

And symmetrically for $Y$.

The Joint CDF is $$F_{X,Y}(x,y) ~=~\begin{cases}0 &:& \text{elsewhere} \\[1ex] \int\limits_{-R}^x \int\limits_{-\sqrt{R^2-s^2}}^{y} (\pi R^2)^{-1}\operatorname d t\operatorname d s &:& x\in(-R;R), y\in(-\sqrt{R^2-x^2~};\sqrt{R^2-x^2~}) \\ F_X(x) &:& x\in(-R;R), y\in[\sqrt{R^2-x^2~};\infty) \\ F_Y(y)&:& y\in(-R;R), x\in[\sqrt{R^2-y^2~};\infty) \\ 1 &:& (x,y)\in[R;\infty)^2\end{cases}$$

Comment: So for the Joint CDF, you would just integrate the term in the brackets, leaving out the indicator function, correct?

Comment: For values within the support; for values above or right....

Comment: are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: I solved this but got an *arcsin* term for the marginal CDF... not sure if thats correct.

Comment: @FelicioGrande The product of the marginal pdf will tell you that they aren't.  Also the fact that it is a disc (thus if you know where $X$ is you know where $Y$ cannot be).

Comment: Do you think it's right to have *arcsin* in the CDF? It sounds a bit weird.